# Renter Area Median Income?

Tags: data, united-states, census

Is there an American Community Survey Data table that has **Renter Area Median Income**. There are tables on Household Median Income and Median Income as a Percent of Rent (B2507).  I am trying to find out the Tract/Block Group's Renter's Median Income, not homeowners and renters together. Table B25122 has estimated total number of renters with breaks of rent for such as total number of renters that make less than $10,000.  I think I could interpolate renter area median income from this table, but hoping there is a table in the ACS data that has area median income just of the

Comment: For questions about open data I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in question:
https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/affhelp/jsf/pages/metadata.xhtml?lang=en&type=table&id=table.en.ACS_16_5YR_B25119#main_content

You'll have to pull the right geography you need but this should give a good start.